# Return a value from loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was creating a function to delete indexes that do not match the required amount of "levels" in my database, then return that array.

The problem is when I do `cleanWinners(winners, guild).then(res => console.log(res))` I receive undefined. I assume the code is not waiting for this function to end before returning the array? How can I fix that?

When I use this code:

```
async function cleanWinners(winners, guild) {
    let returnedArray;

    for (const winner of winners) {
        XP.findOne({serverID: guild.id, userID: winner}, (err, xpTable) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!xpTable) {
                const newXP = new XP({
                    totalXP: 0,
                    xp: 0,
                    level: 0,
                    date: 0,
                    serverID: guild.id,
                    userID: winner
                });
                newXP.save().catch(console.log);
                xpTable = newXP;
            }
            // If they have less than the set amount, get a new winner.
            if (xpTable.level < 1) {
                const index = winners.indexOf(winner);
                delete winners[index];
            }
            console.log('Removed less than level 1', winners);
            let newWinner = getWinners(winners, 1);
            winners = winners.concat(newWinner);
            console.log('New Winner array:', winners);
            returnedArray = winners;
        });
    }
    return returnedArray;
}
// 503418431861948418 should be removed, the other should stay.
// This code returns undefined before the loop even starts. I want this to run AFTER the loop has completed, no matter the amount of entries the array has.
cleanWinners(['209797091457761280','503418431861948418'], message.guild.id)
.then(res => console.log(res));
```

This is the result I get in my console:

````
undefined
Less than 1 level removed [ '209797091457761280', '503418431861948418' ]
New winners array [ '209797091457761280', '503418431861948418' ]
Less than 1 level removed [ '209797091457761280', <1 empty item> ]
New winners array [ '209797091457761280', <1 empty item> ]```
````

Comment: What happens when you change `console.log(res)` to `console.log`?

Comment: This is a classic asynchronous problem in Javascript.  Your `XP.findOne()` calls are asynchronous and they finish sometime LATER.  Further, your function will return before you have any of the values.  Probably you should switch to the promise interface for your database (no plain callbacks any more) and then either use `await` to sequence the database operations in your `for` loop or, if you want to run them in parallel, use `Promise.all()`.  There are likely hundreds of duplicate questions on this topic here that would give you examples for how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is XP.findOne function is async and you passed a callback to it. So it'll not wait for everything to finish before `return returnedArray`.
You should use await on findOne `await XP.findOne(...` then your code will work in the way you're expecting it to.

Here's a great mozilla link for async await if you want to check out
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize XP.findOne was asynchronous.